# S3 object url can be accessed by anyone, how to protect it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

When I map my `userdocumentseo` to `userdocumentsdto` in java I get documents upload url like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/approves3/44/IMG_0189.jpg`.

This link can be opened by anyone whether or not the user is a member of my website. This is not secure. How to protect it?

Comment: What software are you using to share access to files in S3?

Comment: Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. If that URL is accessible to anyone, then you have either added a **Bucket Policy** that makes the bucket public, or you have uploaded the object with `ACL=public-read`. In addition, you would have needed to turn off **S3 Block Public Access**. You should check _why_ it can be publicly accessed.

Comment: How can the website determine whether a user is a "member" of the website and know that they are entitled to access a file? For example, do users login to your website and you only want to provide those files to authenticated users? Please tell us more about how you would like it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides [good documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/awse-protecting-your-media-assets-with-token-authentication/) on how to implement authentication for S3 assets using CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you want to allow access to the resources only for the application users. If that's not the case, you may need to ask more specific question.

> This link can be opened by anyone whether or not the user is a member of my website

If you make the resource public, you basically allowed any unauthenticated access. Regardless from your application or not.

The default (adviced) way to protect the resources is making the object private and make the application creating a signed (temporary) url.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html

```
               GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                   .bucket(bucketName)
                   .key(keyName)
                   .build();

               GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                   .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
                   .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                   .build();

               PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest = presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);
               String theUrl = presignedGetObjectRequest.url().toString();
```